# Access assets in public directory when deploying in subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a Rails app with asset pipelining disabled.

All my javascript files are in public/javascripts
All my css files are in public/stylesheets

I can access the application.js file using the following link:
http://localhost:3000/javascripts/application.js?1424977675

What configuration change should I make, so that the following link works
http://localhost:3000/mydir/myapp/javascripts/application.js?1424977675

I have my application deployed in a subdirectory. Basically I have a docker and the application resides in mydir/myapp folder

I am not able to access the assets using 
http://localhost:3000/mydir/myapp/javascripts/application.js?1424977675

How to I change the relative url for my assets to use http://localhost:3000/mydir/myapp/ instead of http://localhost:3000/

config.asset.prefix doesn't work

I also tried changing config.relative_url_root="/mydir/myapp" without any success